# Create column in a pandas DataFrame based on whether value exists in a different DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to add a column to dfA based on whether or not the job title (and its matching State) exists in dfB.

dfA=

```
Title     State    Income
Cashier   WY       15000
Cashier   WY       20000
Cashier   WY       15000
Manager   WY       25000
Cashier   CO       15000
```

dfB=

```
Title     State    MostFreqIncome
Cashier   WY       15000
```

In English: if a Title/State pair in dfA match any Title/State pair in dfB, create a new column in dfA which gives the MostFreqIncome attached to that Title/State pair.

Desired dfA:

```
Title     State    Income    MostFreqIncome
Cashier   WY       15000     15000
Cashier   WY       20000     15000
Cashier   WY       15000     15000
Manager   WY       25000     NA
Cashier   CO       15000     NA
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
is_in = dfA.Title.isin(dfB.Title) & dfA.State.isin(dfB.State)
```

This gives me False/True, but if it's True I want dfA.MostFreqIncome = dfB.MostFreqIncome. If it's False I want dfA.MostFreqIncome = 'NA'

Comment: Have you tried `pd.merge(dfA, dfB)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `merge` the two DataFrames A and B to create the new DataFrame:

```
>>> dfA.merge(dfB, on=['Title', 'State'], how='left')
     Title State  Income  MostFreqIncome
0  Cashier    WY   15000         15000.0
1  Cashier    WY   20000         15000.0
2  Cashier    WY   15000         15000.0
3  Manager    WY   25000             NaN
4  Cashier    CO   15000             NaN
```

Specifying `how='left'` here means that we're just only `dfA`'s Title/State keys in the merged DataFrame.

Comment: This works, thank you.

One question though - is there a way I can keep the Income as a string? This converted it to a number. (I'm having MemoryError converting it back). The actual variable I'm using looks like a number but it's an ID number.

Comment: That's odd, the type of the 'Income' column should not be affected at all by the merge - which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Turns out it was the original data set that had it as numeric ;)

The merge added the decimal to it. Once I changed the original the string it was fine.

Thanks.